# Unzip in one pass?

Tags: list, haskell

The standard libraries include a function

```
unzip :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
```

The obvious way to define this is

```
unzip xs = (map fst xs, map snd xs)
```

However, this means traversing the list twice to construct the result. What I'm wondering is, is there some way to do this with only one traversal?

Appending to a list is expensive - O(n) in fact. But, as any newbie knows, we can make clever use of laziness and recursion to "append" to a list with a recursive call. Thus, `zip` may easily be implemented as

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
zip (a:as) (b:bs) = (a,b) : zip as bs
```

This trick appear to only work if you're returning *one* list, however. I can't see how to extend this to allow constructing the tails of *multiple* lists simultaneously without ending up duplicating the source traversal.

I always *presumed* that the `unzip` from the standard library manages to do this in a single traversal (that's kind of the whole point of implementing this otherwise trivial function in a library), but I don't actually know how it works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, [it is possible](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#unzip):

```
unzip    =  foldr (\(a,b) ~(as,bs) -> (a:as,b:bs)) ([],[])
```

With explicit recursion, this would look thus:

```
unzip [] = ([], [])
unzip ((a,b):xs) = (a:as, b:bs)
             where (  as,   bs) = unzip xs
```

The reason that the standard library has the irrefutable pattern match `~(as, bs)` is to allow it to work actually lazily:

> Prelude> let unzip' = foldr (\(a,b) ~(as,bs) -> (a:as,b:bs)) ([],[])
>   Prelude> let unzip'' = foldr (\(a,b) (as,bs) -> (a:as,b:bs)) ([],[])
>   Prelude> head . fst $ unzip' [(n,n) | n<-[1..]] 
>   1
>   Prelude> head . fst $ unzip'' [(n,n) | n<-[1..]]
>   *** Exception: stack overflow

Comment: Can you tell me what the '~' means in this context? I came up with the same solution and i didn't need to use it.

Comment: @erdeszt: it's so the function can run lazily in constant space if both lists are consumed without keeping a reference to the head of either. See my GHCi demonstration.

Comment: Hang on, it's even worse: without the irrefutable pattern, to deconstruct even the first tuple you need to evaluate the next recursion step, which needs to deconstruct the tuple, so you need to... you know where this is going.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how lazy pattern matching works. Anyone have any good existing SO answers about this?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid `case x of ~y -> z` is just the same as `let y = (case x of y -> y) in z`.  If you are binding multiple variables spin out the thing you a matching on (the `x` here) as a let to produce sharing and then replicate the pattern match for each variable.  Pattern matching in a let is just lazy matching also, so we can't use that, but this translation works.

Comment: @WillNess: what was that about? I'll leave the formatting like it is now, but REPL demos are more naturally displayed as block quotes rather than source blocks IMO.

Answer (score 7):

The following ideas stem from [The Beautiful Folding](http://squing.blogspot.cz/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html).

When you have two folding operations over a list, you can always perform them at once by folding with keeping both their states. Let's express this in Haskell. First we need to capture what is a folding operation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
import Control.Applicative

data Foldr a b = forall r . Foldr (a -> r -> r) r (r -> b)
```

A folding operation has a folding function, a start value, and a function that produces a result from a final state. By using existential quantification we can hide the type of the state, which is necessary to combine folds with different states.

Applying a `Foldr` to a list is just the matter of calling `foldr` with the appropriate arguments:

```
fold :: Foldr a b -> [a] -> b
fold (Foldr f s g) = g . foldr f s
```

Naturally, `Foldr` is a functor, we can always append a function to the finalizing one:

```
instance Functor (Foldr a) where
    fmap f (Foldr k s r) = Foldr k s (f . r)
```

More interestingly, it's also an `Applicative` functor. Implementing `pure` is easy, we just return a given value and don't fold anything. The most interesting part is `<*>`. It creates a new fold that keeps the states of both give folds and at the end, combines the results.

```
instance Applicative (Foldr a) where
    pure x  = Foldr (\_ _ -> ()) () (\_ -> x)
    (Foldr f1 s1 r1) <*> (Foldr f2 s2 r2)
            = Foldr foldPair (s1, s2) finishPair
      where
        foldPair a ~(x1, x2) = (f1 a x1, f2 a x2)
        finishPair ~(x1, x2) = r1 x1 (r2 x2)
    f *> g  = g
    f <* g  = f
```

Notice (as in leftaroundabout's answer) that we have lazy pattern matches `~` on tuples. This ensures that `<*>` is sufficiently lazy.

Now we can express `map` as a `Foldr`:

```
fromMap :: (a -> b) -> Foldr a [b]
fromMap f = Foldr (\x xs -> f x : xs) [] id
```

With that, defining `unzip` becomes easy. We just combine two maps, one using `fst` and another using `snd`:

```
unzip' :: Foldr (a, b) ([a], [b])
unzip' = (,) <$> fromMap fst <*> fromMap snd

unzip :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
unzip = fold unzip'
```

We can verify that it processes an input only once (and lazily): Both

```
head . snd $ unzip (repeat (3,'a'))
head . fst $ unzip (repeat (3,'a'))
```

yield the correct result.

Comment: ``((/) `on` fromIntegral) <$> fromMap (+) 0 <*> fromMap (const (1+)) 0``? :) but maybe better to call it `doMap`, or `mapping` instead? -- cf. [this](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/08/composable-streaming-folds.html) btw.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for the link, defining `Fold` using monoids instead of  state is a nice idea!